# Exporting HTML Text fields to a Excel Sheet with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel, export, export-to-excel

Is there any way to export HTML Fields from a web application to specific cells in a existing Excel Template.  I am trying to create a web application that would be able to take information entered into it and create a excel sheet with those values.  For example, I want to take the value from the Business Expense Allowance field shown below, and export it into the B9 field in a excel sheet, also below.  How would I accomplish this?

[image: Field Example]

[image: Excel Example]

Comment: Have you tried googling your exact question title?

Comment: I wouldn't be asking if I had already found it.  All I found were articles that talked about exporting tables.  Nothing about text fields.